# How to concat an object name as part of a file path?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I'm trying to make an application to manage some drink recipes...
I need to show the drink image in a `JPanel` already working with the file path like this:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("src/fotos/trinidad.jpg");
```

The problem is that when I try to set this path setting it with the object name, the image is not being loaded.

```
String s = ("src/fotos/"+b.getNome().toLowerCase()+".jpg");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(s);
```

Printing this string `s` I have this result:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

> src/fotos/trinidad.jpg

Apparently it looks the same path, but the image is not being loaded.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `src` folder does not exist when your code is compiled and ran, by the way. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/trinidad.jpg"));` would generate a more reasonable result, but I'd be tempted to using `ImageIO.read` instead, as it throws a `IOException` if the image can't be read

Comment: To add to the comment of @cricket_007. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: I tried with @MadProgrammer sugestion and kinda fixed my code. The thing is that it was not the problem causing my application to not load the image correctly. I had to add the drinks again to solve the problem. Thx for the fast answer and for teaching me about embedded resoruce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, if the image (path) does not exist you can catch the exception and treat accordingly.

```
    BufferedImage drinkImage = null;
    try {
        drinkImage= ImageIO.read(new File("src/fotos/trinidad.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(drinkImage);

    // Put image in your JPanel
```

Comment: You solution is as good as @MadProgrammer one.
I'm currently using `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/trinidad.jpg"));`